# Difference between The Past Definite, Imperfect, and Past Indefinite tenses

Tags: grammaire

I'm trying to learn French by myself (now reading Karl C. Sandburg's book French for Reading), and got confused in the three "past time" tenses: Past Definite (**PD**), Imperfect (**I**), and Past Indefinite (**PI**).

As the book says,

1. **PI** could be translated into English Simple Past Tense  (*I spoke*) or The Perfect Tense (*I have spoken*) , however, when to choose which is unclear;
2. **PD** could only be translated into English Simple Past Tense (*I spoke*), however, the difference between **PI** and **PD** is unclear, so translating from English to French is my problem;
3. The Imperfect (**I**) could be translated into English Simple Past Tense (*I spoke*), Past Continuous Time (*I was speaking*), or  *I used to spoke*, and the usage is summarized as 3 cases --  **a)** past description or characterization , e.g. *Sa maîtresse pas une personne agréable* (*Her mistress was not a pleasant person*), *Sa maison se trouvait entre un passage et une ruelle* (*Her house was situated/found between a passage way and an alley*) ; **b)** customary or habitual past action, e.g. *Elle se levait dès l'aube.*(*She would/used to get up at dawn.*); **c**) action incomplete (in progress ) at a specified or implied moment in the past , e.g. *Alors qu'il se promenaient , ils virent venir à eux des hommes armés.* (*While they were strolling, they saw some armed men coming toward them.*) , -- but these seems overlapping with **PD**, what's the difference between them?

So I got confused , what's exactly the differences among them? Without figuring this out I could only read French and randomly translate them to a particular English tense; and vice versa.

Comment: Tenses don't usually correspond form one language to the other - neither in denomination nor in use. And specially so when you compare French to English or German which have far fewer tenses. [This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/French/Grammar/Tenses) will give you the names in French, [these](http://www.gcse.com/french/tenses.htm) the basics - how form them, when to use them. On French Language searching by tags you will find info on the various tenses such as http://french.stackexchange.com/q/17031/358 or http://french.stackexchange.com/q/8337/358

Answer (score 1):

[Found this website that will help you better than I can](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic22744-differences-entre-le-passe-simple-le-passe-compose-et-limparfait.html)

I have never heard of Passed Definite and Passed indefinite.  In school I learned about Imparfait, Passé simple, Passé composé.

Comment: Thx but.... Anything in English?